# Having issues with ethernet connection

Tags: raspbian, ethernet

I was trying to use apt-get update and it didn't work because the pi wouldn't connect via ethernet (even though it is plugged in). I tried pinging google but it says network is unreachable. I checked the lights on the pi and the FDX light is solid green, LNK is flashing green, and 100 light is solid orange. the only useful info that ifconfig returns is the mac address.  Can someone tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Nevermind, turns out the port in the switch I was using that connected to the pi was burnt out. Plugged into another port and now it works.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it.